# DataTable not Showing Data from Json Objects

Tags: json, object, asp.net-core, datatables

HTML view page for this Controller Actions. I want to view all json action result through this View Page. But Json Data Not showing in DataTables all though Json get All data correctly

```html
<h1>Leave Application Logs</h1>
<br />
<div class="row p-4 border rounded">
    <table id="mytable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width: 100%">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr class="table-info">
                <th>
                    Employee Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Start Date
                </th>
                <th>
                    End Date
                </th>
                <th>
                    Leave Type
                </th>
                <th>
                    Requested Date
                </th>
                <th>
                    Approval Status
                </th>
                <th>
                    Actions
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>

@section Scripts{
    <script src="leaveapplication.js">    </script>
}
```

C# Asp .net Controller Action

```c#
public ActionResult GetAll()
        {
            var leaveRequest = _uow.LeaveRequest.GetAll(includeProperties: "LeaveType", includeProperty: "RequestingEmployee", includeProperte: "ApprovedBy");
            var leaveRequestModel = _mapper.Map<List<LeaveRequestVm>>(leaveRequest);
            var model = new AdminLeaveRequestVm
            {
                TotalRequest = leaveRequestModel.Count,
                ApprovedRequest = leaveRequestModel.Count(x => x.Approved == true),
                PendingRequest = leaveRequestModel.Count(x => x.Approved == null),
                RejectedRequest = leaveRequestModel.Count(x => x.Approved == false),
                LeaveRequest = leaveRequestModel
            };
            return Json(new { data = model });
        }
```

DataTable js File

```js
var dataTable;

$(document).ready(function() {
  loadDataTable();
});

function loadDataTable() {
  dataTable = $('#tblData').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
      "url": "/leaveRequests/GetAll"
    },
    "columns": [{
        "data": "leaveRequest.requestingEmployee.firstname",
        "width": "10%"
      },
      {
        "data": "leaveRequest.startDate",
        "width": "10%"
      },
      {
        "data": "leaveRequest.endDate",
        "width": "10%"
      },
      {
        "data": "leaveRequest.leaveType.name",
        "width": "10%"
      },
      {
        "data": "leaveRequest.dateRequested, "
        width ": "
        10 % " }, {
        "data": "leaveRequest.approved, "
        width ": "
        10 % " }, {
        "data": "id",
        "render": function(data) {
          return `
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <a href="/leaveRequest/Create/${data}" class="btn btn-warning text-white" style="cursor:pointer">
                                    <i class="fas fa-edit"></i> 
                                </a>
                            </div>
                           `;
        },
        "width": "40%"
      }
    ],
    "language": {
      "emptyTable": "no data found"
    },
    "width": "100%"
  });
}


}
`
```

[Json Data Getting From System Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAwVP.png)

Anyone can help me? I'm getting totally stack there. I already see some related stackoverflow question but not get my problem solution

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please can you edit your question, and include the JSON as formatted text, not as a link to a screenshot. Please also add the code which creates the DataTable, and which uses the JSON data (also as formatted text). Thanks.

Comment: @andrewjames Thanks for your Response. Please Can you help me now? I can't added Json Data as code snippet. If you need anything else let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working demo like below:

Model:

```
public class AdminLeaveRequestVm
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TotalRequest { get; set; }
    public int ApprovedRequest { get; set; }
    public int PendingRequest { get; set; }
    public int RejectedRequest { get; set; }
    public List<LeaveRequest> LeaveRequest { get; set; }
}
public class LeaveRequest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateRequested { get; set; }
    public bool Approved { get; set; }
    public RequestingEmployee RequestingEmployee { get; set; }
    public leaveType leaveType { get; set; }
}
public class RequestingEmployee
{
    public string firstname { get; set; }
}
public class leaveType
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string age { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<h1>Leave Application Logs</h1>
<br />
<div class="row p-4 border rounded">
    <table id="mytable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width: 100%">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr class="table-info">
                <th>
                    Employee Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Start Date
                </th>
                <th>
                    End Date
                </th>
                <th>
                    Leave Type
                </th>
                <th>
                    Requested Date
                </th>
                <th>
                    Approval Status
                </th>
                <th>
                    Actions
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>

@section Scripts{
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            loadDataTable();
        });

        function loadDataTable() {
            $('#mytable').DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Home/GetAll"
                },
                "columns": [{
                    "data": "requestingEmployee",
                    "width": "10%",
                    "render": function (d) {
                        if (d !== null) {
                            var table = "";

                                table += "<tr><td>" + d.firstname + "</td></tr><br/>";

                            return table;
                        } else {
                            return "";
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "data": "startDate",
                    "width": "10%"
                },
                {
                    "data": "endDate",
                    "width": "10%"
                },
                {
                    "data": "leaveType",
                    "width": "10%",
                    "render": function (d) {
                        if (d !== null) {
                            var table = "";

                                table += "<tr><td>" + d.name + "</td></tr><br/>";

                            return table;
                        } else {
                            return "";
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "data": "dateRequested",
                    "width ": "10%"
                },
                {
                    "data": "approved",
                    "width ": "10 % "
                },
                {
                    "data": "id",
                    "render": function (data) {
                        return `
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <a href="/leaveRequest/Create/${data}" class="btn btn-warning text-white" style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                `;
                    },
                    "width": "40%"
                }
                ],
                "language": {
                    "emptyTable": "no data found"
                },
                "width": "100%"
            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetAll()
{
    var leaveRequest = new List<LeaveRequest>() {
            new LeaveRequest(){
            Approved=false,
            DateRequested=DateTime.Parse("2020-10-02"),
            EndDate = DateTime.Parse("2020-09-02"),
            Id=4,
            leaveType=new leaveType(){ name="name1",age="age1" },
            RequestingEmployee=new RequestingEmployee(){ firstname="fname1" },
            StartDate = DateTime.Parse("2020-09-02")
            },
            new LeaveRequest(){
            Approved=true,
            DateRequested=DateTime.Parse("2020-01-02"),
            EndDate = DateTime.Parse("2020-03-02"),
            Id=4,
            leaveType=new leaveType(){ name="name2",age="age2" },
            RequestingEmployee=new RequestingEmployee(){ firstname="fname2" },
            StartDate = DateTime.Parse("2020-09-12")
            }
    };
    return Json(new { data = leaveRequest });
}
```

Result:
[image]
If you want to pass `AdminLeaveRequestVm`,you need to modify something like below(I don't configure entirely because I think the first approach is much better):
View:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        loadDataTable();
    });

    function loadDataTable() {
        $('#mytable').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Home/GetAll"
            },
            "columns": [
            {
                "data": "leaveRequest",
                "width": "10%",
                "render": function (d) {
                    if (d !== null) {
                        var table = "";
                        $.each(d, function (k, v) {
                            table += "<tr><td>" + v.startDate + "</td></tr><br/>";
                        });
                        return table;
                    } else {
                        return "";
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "data": "leaveRequest",
                "width": "10%",
                "render": function (d) {
                    if (d !== null) {
                        var table = "";
                        $.each(d, function (k, v) {
                            table += "<tr><td>" + v.endDate + "</td></tr><br/>";
                        });
                        return table;
                    } else {
                        return "";
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "data": "leaveRequest",
                "width": "10%",
                "render": function (d) {
                    if (d !== null) {
                        var table = "";
                        $.each(d, function (k, v) {                               
                            table += "<tr><td>" + v.leaveType.name + "</td></tr><br/>";
                        });
                        return table;
                    } else {
                        return "";
                    }
                }
            },
             {
                    "data": "leaveRequest",
                    "width": "10%",
                    "render": function (d) {
                        if (d !== null) {
                            var table = "";
                            $.each(d, function (k, v) {
                                table += "<tr><td>" + v.dateRequested + "</td></tr><br/>";
                            });
                            return table;
                        } else {
                            return "";
                        }
                    }
             },
             {
                    "data": "leaveRequest",
                    "width": "10%",
                    "render": function (d) {
                        if (d !== null) {
                            var table = "";
                            $.each(d, function (k, v) {
                                table += "<tr><td>" + v.approved + "</td></tr><br/>";
                            });
                            return table;
                        } else {
                            return "";
                        }
                    }
             }
            ],
            "language": {
                "emptyTable": "no data found"
            },
            "width": "100%"
        });
    }
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetAll()
{
    var leaveRequest = new List<LeaveRequest>() {
            new LeaveRequest(){
            Approved=false,
            DateRequested=DateTime.Parse("2020-10-02"),
            EndDate = DateTime.Parse("2020-09-02"),
            Id=4,
            leaveType=new leaveType(){ name="name1",age="age1" },
            RequestingEmployee=new RequestingEmployee(){ firstname="fname1" },
            StartDate = DateTime.Parse("2020-09-02")
            },
            new LeaveRequest(){
            Approved=true,
            DateRequested=DateTime.Parse("2020-01-02"),
            EndDate = DateTime.Parse("2020-03-02"),
            Id=4,
            leaveType=new leaveType(){ name="name2",age="age2" },
            RequestingEmployee=new RequestingEmployee(){ firstname="fname2" },
            StartDate = DateTime.Parse("2020-09-12")
            }
    };
    var list = new List<AdminLeaveRequestVm>();
    var model = new AdminLeaveRequestVm
    {
        Id = 1,
        TotalRequest = 1,
        ApprovedRequest = 0,
        PendingRequest = 0,
        RejectedRequest = 1,
        LeaveRequest = leaveRequest
    };
    //must return list instead of model
    list.Add(model);
    return Json(new { data = list });
}
```